# Intermittent stalling Camry

Tags: toyota, stall, camry, intermittent-problems

The car is a 96 Camry with the 2.2 L engine.

It will start, and within 10 or so minutes it stumbles and stalls. Upon restart it starts and shuts right back off. Wait 5-10 minutes, and it will start and run perfect all day long.

Reader shows code P1300, primary ignition. I have replaced coil, cap and rotor, plugs. Wires are good.

Comment: Could be a problem with the fuel system, maybe a clogged filter, a plugged/bent fuel return line, or an overheating and failing fuel pump?